# Is there any way for javascript to plot kml or gpx data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

Let's say I have a site where local users can upload their favorite hikes to share. But some users don't have the ability to get gpx or kml data.

Are there any open source options for the users to plot their own hikes, like in a google maps window?

If not, what would be the best way to go about doing this, if any?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Drawing Tools in the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools) to plot the hike, then convert that data to KML or gpx.

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html) built from a previous version of [blitz-gmap-editor](https://code.google.com/p/blitz-gmap-editor/), there were some changes made to it since I took that snapshot.